# Is it possible to check max storage address of a SD card via a command?

Tags: sd

How much memory can an SD card hold?

I am not going to use a data format. I want to use it as an upgradeable internal storage. So I want to know in which range of addresses I can work. Maybe there is a command for this?

I don't know if it's relevant, but I am using it in [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) mode.

Comment: Have a look into the Reduced Block Commands. They are the low level interface the cards use.

Comment: Do you want the SD command that gives you card storage size?  This is generally found during card initialisation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is held within the CSD register of the SD card, which is mandatory and must be present.  It is 12 bits wide (CSD v1.0) or 22 bits wide (CSD v2.0).

[image: CSD v2]

You need to do some work to get the actual size in bytes, which is also explained in the specifications.  For CSD v1 the calculation is shown below:

[image: Calculating total size]

But note that because you address the card by block the C_SIZE parameter is probably the one you are after.

You don't say how you are accessing the card (1-bit SD, 4-bit SD or SPI).  When using the SD memory card protocol `CMD9` (SEND_CSD) is used to obtain the CSD register.

In SPI mode you use a block read to obtain the CSD in the same way you would read data.  This works by sending `CMD9` the same as SD mode, then a block read is initiated using `CMD17`.

Further information is available in the "[Physical Layer Simplified Specification](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/simplified_specs/part1_410.pdf)" which is a free document you can download from sdcard.org.